# Baggage check through Johannesburg

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage, johannesburg

I will be flying to Windhoek from Dublin through Johannesburg in August with British Airways. We are flying Comair to Windhoek. Will I need to collect my bag and recheck it again?

Answer (score 2):

Windhoek is an international connection. According to [this post](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/africa/1009900-jnb-johannesburg-airport-connect-facilities-layover-etc-consolidated.html):

If the bags are not tagged through, you will have to pick them up, clear customs, and recheck them.

If the bags are tagged through, you don't have to collect them, but you should verify the tag numbers with the connecting airline; if you don't, the bags will not be loaded. However, the post suggests that if you have enough time, it is safer to take the bags through customs and recheck them instead.

Comment: If I read that site you link I see that for International to Domestic flight you need to get your luggage and go through customs. It is international to International that you can use the tagged through-verify with airline system.

Comment: @Willeke If I'm not mistaken, Windhoek is not in South Africa, so it's an international-international connection.

Comment: @f'' You are not mistaken: Windhoek is the capital of Namibia.